# WPF c# mosue enter of data table with Background

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, background, cell

I create a date grid with setting background cell by binding
my flowing code in WPF look like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Background" >
      <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay" ConverterParameter="O0" Converter="                       {StaticResource tCBackroundConvertor}">
          <Binding Mode="OneWay"
           Path="TimesInOut" />
          <Binding ElementName="O0"
            ode="OneWay" Path="Name" />
        </MultiBinding>
      </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
   </Style>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```

and my convertor look like this:

```
 public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
          string type = parameter.ToString();
          List<List<string>> times = value[0] as List<List<string>>;
          if (times != null)
              if (times.Count() > int.Parse(type[1].ToString()))
                  if
                  (times[int.Parse(type[1].ToString())][type[0].ToString() == "I" ? 0 : 1] == "")
                      return new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.MediumVioletRed);
                  else
                      return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
              else
                  return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
          else
              return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
      }
```

the result is this:[image: [the data table result]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNOkK.png)

but when I i click the row to edit row I cant sea what inside because its look like this:
[image: [date table when mouse enter]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fExQS.png)

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
```

to

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
```

So the DataGridCell will inherit its old style.

Comment: Any problem? You had accepted the answer, can i help you further?

Comment: I'm new in stack overflow and i don't succeed to do it